# Do I need to set secret_token for Rails 4.1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

> /config/secrets.rb:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 94730841d80e811de49fdb8ab9ed
test:
  secret_key_base: 26400b050b69a3ae3297c7

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

There is no

> config/initializers/secret_token.rb

Where Have I put the secret_token?

Comment: Yes you do have to set secret_token.
I don't understand a question: I just generated new app using 'rails new' and it has the file.
May be you cloned some code from a repo and the owner of that, excluded the file from tracked files ))

Comment: See your gemfile.lock to ensure that your app are using Rails 4.1

Comment: yeah, my fault: 4.0.4 )
little dig in faq reveals that it deprecated in 4.1 and has been replaced by secrets yaml: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml